# Animate views according scroller in a listView / GridView

Tags: android, android-animation

How to animate the items above a listView or grid according to the scroller in a ListView / GridView.

In the video below, an example of what I mean.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBCZ_Spn_Pg&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic ObservableListView (Search on github) should help you. Then you can response to scroll events and animate/translate/fade the other views around or above your scrollable content.